# How do I speed up sortBy or sortBykey method in spark?

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, methods

I've been trying to speed up `sortBy()` or `sortByKey()` method in spark.

When I run spark app with these methods, It consumes the most time when sorting in total program time.

Here is example code. Both `sortBy()` and `sortByKey()` are slow.

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                 .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _).sortByKey(true, 1)
```

If I have a big data file, Is there an effective way to sort for the big data file?

Comment: if you are not care about the entire sorted data ( which is most case ) only take some certain number of sorted data, using `takeOrdered(num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T])` may significantly reduce the time spark consumes. otherwise, the average sorting algorithm is `Nlog(N)`

Comment: Thank you! 
Now I checked the `takeOrdered` method. It converts data type RDD to Array. If I use `saveAsTextFile` method to save a file that uses the `takeOrdered` method, I must convert Array to RDD again. So I don't know if it is more efficient to use `takeOrdered` than just `sortBy()` or `sortByKey()`.

Comment: takeOrdered using `PriorityQueue` on each partition, so it should be more fast, as array will be retrieved only in the master node, you can just write the result using foreach, and convert it to rdd back will not be a big issue, I presumed.

Comment: I appreciate your advise!
I tested the running time of `sortBy()` and `takeOrdered()`.
`takeOrdered()` is a little faster than `sortBy()` as you said.
But, it is still slow to process for big data... Should I take this part? or
Is there other method to solve this problem?

Comment: How many records do you have and how many ordered records do you want to retrieve? be noted that `reduceByKey(_ + _)` is sort of slow too.

Comment: I generated billions of data for the experiments in spark.

Does `reduceByKey(_ + _)` sort?  When I experimented, It was not sorted.

So I thought  `reduceByKey(_ + _)` could not be sorted.

Comment: yes, `reduceByKey(_+_)` will not sort, but it will do a [shuffle](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Could you answer one more question? If you don't mind.
Starting Spark 1.2.0, sort Shuffle is the default shuffle algorithm used by Spark. [link](https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/)
 I'm using Spark 2.0.0. so why does not be sorted using `reduceByKey(_+_)`?

Comment: That's beyond my knowledge, you may have to open another question to get a answer about that ;D

Comment: Okay~ Thanks for your reply!
Have a nice day~